# UAC Enforcement for ProgramData in Windows Server 2012

Tags: uac, windows-server-2012, programdata

A file is created under C:\ProgramData\Example. This file is created with 'Full Control' permission for Administrators group. A domain user with Administrators privilege is able to overwrite file with new copy in Windows Server 2008 R2. When same is tried in Windows Server 2012, it is failing with Access denied. I disabled UAC by following procedure mentioned @ https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13953.windows-server-2012-deactivating-uac.aspx.

After change, I am able to overwirte file with new copy in Windows Server 2012. Is there any change in UAC behavior with respect to C:\ProgramData folder and its content in Windows Server 2012?

Regards,
Madhan

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that, by default, regular **Users** are allowed to create/modify files in `ProgramData` on Windows Server 2012/2008 R2/2008:

[image: ss]

I'd be curious to see the offending file's permissions, as well as the containing folder's permissions. Files, when moved, keep the permissions they were created with, and do not gain the permissions of their new folder location.

So it's not a "UAC" issue, but an NTFS permissions issue.

Comment: Thanks Boyd. We hit this problem because permission was inherting to the user only from Administrator Group. We added permission for the right group and assigned the user. with this change issue was solved.